# It takes 2 clicks for change in angular directive

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, angularjs-directive

Ok, so I'll just start off saying I'm almost certain this bug is either arising from my lack of understanding of isolate scoping in angular directives or some weird interaction between directives and the angular google maps markers directive.

Anyways, the issue is that I have an instance of the angular-google-maps stuff in my main controller, and I have a  tag within that. I also have a directive which is captures user inputs and uses them to populate a list in the main controller for the  tag to do its thing. I pass in an object and function from the main controller into the directive's isolate scope.

The weird thing is that within my directives, I have bound this function onto a button click for a form, and for some reason, it takes 2 clicks to get the marker to appear. The function fires the first click, it has all the right values and everything, but the marker doesn't appear. Another weird I checked was simply calling the method twice in a row for one click which didn't work (still required 2 button presses).

The function modifies the array in the main controller (I have a feeling this is the root of the issue) which is used by the  tag as a list of markers. Any ideas on why this could be happening? If it doesn't seem like an obvious misunderstanding of Angular scoping, I can post code.

Comment: My first thought is your data is happening outside of the digest loop. And if that's the case then adding a `$scope.$digest()` after your data is updated might solve it (or give you a console error). Posting code would help though.

Comment: That was it! If you put your comment as an answer I will mark it as so. I am curious as to why I would need to force a digest in that situation, but I guess if I study that cycle a little bit I can probably figure it out.

Comment: If its in a callback, a bind in the controller, or a timeout/interval (among other things) it brings it outside of the digest loop and requires a forced digest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first thought is your data is happening outside of the digest loop. And if that's the case then adding a $scope.$digest() after your data is updated might solve it (or give you a console error).

Comment: @NicholkasThomas, where exactly the **$scope.$digest()** should be palced?   In  my case, i have  a **Modal Directive**, which opens up the modal with data transcluded(data  from within  the modal directive). And the **directive** will be opened or closed based on the  **button's click function**,(**ie: the on click () will take care of setting the modal's initiation value to open or close**). So i placed **$scope.$digest()** as the last statement  of the click(), but after that, i get an error saying **$apply already in progress**...
Kindly help.